# Is the word "Ambivalent" = "Ambiguous"?

Tags: meaning, differences

`Ambivalent` = `uncertainty to do two opposite or conflicting things` = `of doubtful or uncertain nature` = `Ambiguous`

The above is my understanding of the two word `Ambivalent` and `Ambiguous`. Are there any kind souls that can enlighten me by telling me the distinct differences (if there is any) of both the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That which is *ambiguous* has the potential to be interpreted in more than one way. For example, if I say ‘I’ve never read a book like it', it’s ambiguous whether I’m impressed by the book’s positive or negative qualities. *Ambivalent*, on the other hand, describes a person’s attitude. If I can see both good and bad points in an argument you might say that my attitude was ambivalent.

Comment: So, I can say that I can use the word `ambiguous` if I can't see the good points and bad points. However, if I can see the good points and bad points, then the word `ambivalent` would be more suitable.

Comment: No, not quite that. If you are unsure of the meaning of something, if it might mean one thing or another, then it is ambiguous. 'Ambivalent' describes you attitude if you feel two ways about something.

Comment: Now I see it. `Ambivalent` for people attitude while `ambiguous` for something that can have multiple meanings which might contrast with each other. (This time, do I get it right?)

Comment: +1 Thanks Barrie. Now I have a better understanding.

Comment: Yes, you could say that very broadly: 'ambiguous' for whatever it is you experience, 'ambivalent' for your attitude towards something.

Comment: Keep in mind that 'ambiguous' tends to refer to a meaning that is unclear in some way. For example, "Did you see the man with the binoculars?" - it could mean "Did you see the man who was using binoculars?", or "Did you see the man, through your binoculars?". 'Ambivalent', however, tends to apply to having two conflicting (normally opposite) emotions or opinions simultaneously, often where those feelings are usually expected to be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Things are ambiguous, which means "open to interpretation".  People are ambivalent about things, which means "hold opposing attitudes towards something".  Things aren't ambivalent, because they don't hold opinions.  People can also be ambiguous if, for example, they say something that can be interpreted in multiple ways; people being ambiguous is likely to make you feel ambivalent about trusting them.

Comment: So, I can say that the word *ambivalent* is only for people but the word *ambiguous* can apply for people and things?

Comment: Generally, yes.

Comment: +1 Thanks Ben. Now I have a better understanding.